# Total potential energy for two charged particles

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, charge, potential-energy, coulombs-law

I'm trying to formulate a Lagrangian equation for a system of two charged particles. They have respective masses $m_1$ and $m_2$, and respective position vectors $\vec{x_1}(t)$ and $\vec{x_2}(t)$.

First, I am asked to find the force that particle one exerts on particle two, and vice-versa. I used the vector method suggested on Wikipedia, and found these forces to be:
$$F_1 = \frac{q_1q_2}{4\pi\varepsilon_0}\frac{\vec{x_1}(t) - \vec{x_2}(t)}{|\vec{x_1}(t) - \vec{x_2}(t)|^3}$$
and similarly
$$F_2 = \frac{q_1q_2}{4\pi\varepsilon_0}\frac{\vec{x_2}(t) - \vec{x_1}(t)}{|\vec{x_2}(t) - \vec{x_1}(t)|^3}$$

Now I need to find the *total potential energy* of the system. I have done extensive googling but cannot seem to find a method that reconciles what I have with what I need. What am I missing? If I add these forces together, they appear to sum to zero. Clearly I am approaching it the wrong way.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: The potential energy of the system depends on all coordiantes, in your case $U\propto 1/|x_1-x_2|$. This resul is achieved by integration of any particular force you have written. The system Lagrangian has also a sum of kinetic terms for each particle.

Answer (score -1):

Remember that force is the negative gradient of the potential for a single particle in a potential $\vec F(\vec x)=-\nabla V(\vec x)$. Now for an interaction potential $U(\vec x_1,\vec x_2)$, the forces on each of the two particles are given by the gradients *with respect to the coordinate of the particle*. One usually denotes that $\vec F_1=-\vec\nabla_{x_1}U(\vec x_1,\vec x_2)$ und likewise for $\vec F_2$. $\vec\nabla_{x_1}$ is the 3-vector of derivatives with respect to the three components of $\vec x_1$ but not w.r.t. $\vec x_2$.

Note that if $U$ only really depends on the difference of the coordinates of both particles, $\vec x_1-\vec x_2$, then, by the chain rule, one immediately finds that $\vec\nabla_{x_1}U(\vec x_1-\vec x_2)=-\vec\nabla_{x_2}U(\vec x_1-\vec x_2)$, i.e. Newton's famous action$=-$reaction.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to use cartesian coordinates, it's best to simply assume that both the charges are sitting on, say, the x axis (you could just as well put it on the y or the z). Then, they have position vectors $ r_{1} = \langle x_{1}, 0, 0 \rangle $ and $ r_{2} = \langle x_{2}, 0, 0 \rangle$. 
The reason you can do this is because the only relevant axis is the line that connects the two particles. The coulomb force acts in the direction of this axis, and its magnitude is proportional to the distance between them along this axis. 
The distance between them is $ | x_{1} - x_{2}| $ and the forces are
 $$ F_{12} = k_{e} q_{1}q_{2} \frac{1}{(x_{1} - x_{2})^{2}} = F_{21} $$

The potential energy is just the negative of the amount of work required to assemble the system, plus some constant that is associated with the initial state. 
We can say that when the two particles are infinitely far apart, the potential energy is zero.

Now, let's assemble the system by bringing in the charges from their infinite separation. The energy to place the first charge at $ x_{1} $ is 0 because there are no forces acting on it while we bring it in from infinity. However, to bring the second charge to $ x_{2} $, an amount of work equal to $ W = \int_{\infty}^{x_{2}} F_{12} dx  = -U $ must be done because it interacts with the first charge sitting at $ x_{1} $. 
Therefore, $$ U = -\int_{\infty}^{x_{2}}  k_{e} q_{1} q_{2} \frac{1}{(x_{1} - x)^{2}} dx = k_{e} q_{1} q_{2} \frac{1}{(x_{1} - x_{2})} $$

Now it's clear that $ U $ only depends on the distance between the two particles. Therefore, we can write it in a more general form as $$ U = k_{e} q_{1} q_{2} \frac{1}{| \mathbf{r_{1}} - \mathbf{r_{2}}|} $$.